# How do you store network variables for re-use in functional programming languages?

Tags: functional-programming

How do you manage reusable state retrieved from a network in a fp language during runtime?

I know of atoms in Clojure, but nothing of other languages. Is there a way to manage network data within state using pure fp principles? If there's no mutable state, the service would have to make a network request each time it needed a piece of data for a function [which needed that data as an input]. This seems very expensive.

Comment: *Every* functional programming language has some kind of "escape hatch" to cause effects, otherwise it would be futile. If you can do a network request, you can also store the value in some stateful variable.

Comment: You bind names to values so you do store but you don't reassign or mutate. Instead of reassigning you call a function and pass the new name binding as an argument. Instead of mutating you copy a composite value. In order to make the latter efficient composite values are encoded as balanced trees. Then you can only copy the path to the modified component and share the rest.

Comment: @scriptum that makes sense, but what about the situation where one server (S1) needs to wait for user action to login to another server (S2). When S1 gets told to login to S2, how does it bind a value to a name during runtime?

Comment: @ohryan Let's assume our language handles DB requests async. We need a type that takes an asynchronously produced value and contains it from here on, i.e. it must not offer means to get the value back. So instead of passing it to a function, we do it the other way arond by lifting other functions into the effectful context of the value. Only our type needs to know how this works. It encodes how composition works for this particular effect. This way the rest of the program remains pure.

Comment: The type I am talking about is a functor, applicative or monad, depending on how much expressivness you need. It is a simplified explanation that should give a rough intuition.

Comment: @scriptum okay, I need to research these a bit more before I can appropriately respond. I'll be looking deep into these tomorrow, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know of atoms in Clojure, but nothing of other languages

All FP languages will most likely have a construct similar to Clojure's atom, for example Haskell has TVar, MVar, TMVar which are similar managed safe mutable containers like Atom and Ref are in Clojure. This is because state is often unavoidable, and memory is not infinite, so at some point you need mutation, but what FP languages do is isolate that mutation and manage it so you limit its impact on program complexity and safety.

Now probably what you want to hear as you're trying to keep things purely functional and I feel your question is... but aren't these mutable state containers non functional?

Well the answer is to keep to a pure FP style, you need to model things as a data-flow and pass state along. You maintain state because it's constantly passed along to the next thing running or waiting. Sometimes that's more ackward than good though, and lots of frameworks in FP languages won't do that, they'll use a managed mutable container like an atom.

So here's the gist:

```
waitForNextCommand(state[])
-- command, state -->
if state missing token
  -- state[] -->
  getTokenFromA
  -- state[token] -->
  callB
  -- state[token] -->
  waitForNextCommand(state[token]) ;; recursive
else if state has token
  -- state[token] -->
  callB
  -- state[token] -->
  waitForNextCommand(state[token]) ;; recursive
```

Now there is no global state, and no mutable containers, only functions of immutable input to output calling each other in a data-flow which is recursive, yet you won't call getTokenFromA if you already have a token.

That said, waitForNextCommand won't be pure, and that's normal, at the boundary something has to be impure as it interacts with the user or external world.